# Getting exception at RegexParser.ScanRegex()

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I have this regex pattern and I have tested it on regex101 and it works as I want it to.

```
((der|die|das)\ .*?),.*+\n.*\n(.*?)\n
```

I get the exception at this line:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"((der|die|das)\ .*?),.*+\n.*\n(.*?)\n");
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What is the exception you get? What is the plus sign before the first `\n` for? It seems to be a syntax error there.

Comment: Why do you have a space between the backslash and the period?  The backslash says you have a control character and there is no such thing as a control space.

Answer (score 3):

Regex has different *flavors*, implemented by different regex engines. Regex101 lets you use PCRE or JavaScript. .NET implements its own regex engine, with somewhat different features.

In your case, the [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) syntax `.*+` is *not* supported by .NET, but it's simply a syntactic sugar, so you can replace that with an equivalent [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html): `(?>.*)`

Note that this particular item in your regex seems dubious here, so maybe just remove that `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the + after the "*+\n.*"

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"((der|die|das)\ .*?),.*\n.*\n(.*?)\n");
```

Is a nested quantifiers

```
+ The plus sign indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element.
* The asterisk indicates zero or more occurrences of the preceding element.
```